# property in container view controller is not giving correct value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I created a `container view controller` which contains five `child view controllers`.

I created a `@property BOOL flag` in `container view controller` and in `awakeFromNib` I set it to `YES`.

When accessing this property in `container view controller` its `YES` but when accessing from `child view controllers` its `NO`.

I am **not** creating new instance of `container view controller` in `child view controllers` but why I am getting `NO`?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @S.J : You should share your code to help you out :) Anyway I hope you are accessing your container view controller in childVC as (self.parent as? ContainerVC). flag, if not please change

Comment: yes I am accessing it through parent property

Comment: how you are accessing the property of parent class in child view controller ?

Comment: Assuming, from your above comment, that you are accessing the property in childC as `(self.parent as? ContainerVC).flag`, the qestion is **where** you are accessing it. If you are trying to access it before view set up, it will not work. Try accessing it post `viewDidAppear` in childVC.